# Pass variables through to ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am fairly new to AJAX so am using 'Jquery Form'.

I need to pass the `entry` and `path` variables through the the `success callback`.

```
var optionsUpdate = {
    data: { entry: entry, path: path },
    success: updateLoad,
}; 

function updateLoad(data) {
    var wrapper = '.recent-order-item'+data.entry;
    $(wrapper).load(data.path);
}

$('.status_update').submit(function() {
    optionsUpdate.data.entry = $(this).attr('id');
    optionsUpdate.data.path = '/orders/embed-order-item/'+optionsUpdate.data.entry;
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(optionsUpdate); 
    return false; 
});
```

Can anyone explain how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update object values on submit -

```
$('.status_update').submit(function() {
    optionsUpdate.data.entry = $(this).attr('id');
    optionsUpdate.data.path = '/orders/embed-order-item/'+optionsUpdate.data.entry;
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(optionsUpdate); 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my code in my question to what you show. I presumed I would be able to call by using 'data.entry', but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it says optionsUpdate.data is undefined

Comment: @user2889310 .. i see that you have removed data object from your optionsUpdate object... restore that....

Comment: I have updated the code again. I have tried adding the data object with the above, and data.entry etc, but it shows as 'entry' being undefined.

Comment: set it like `-->` `data: { entry: '', path: '' }`

Comment: Okay, now no errors, but the var shows as 'undefined'

Comment: Surely, setting the data atrributes as '' is why they are empty? How can I set them as the variables?

Comment: @user2889310 data that is passed in this function `updateLoad(data)` is not your data object.. but it is the data returned by server..check  on server ..if you are returning data properly ..

Comment: Nothing is being returned. I dont need anything returned other than the variables I am trying to get to pass through.